# Vectorize a jpeg logo in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo, jpg

I've got a jpeg logo file that I need to vectorize, however I have never done this before. I have read through a few tutorials but I was wondering if anyone had any tips as I've been finding it quite difficult.
If anyone knows of an easy way to go about this in Adobe Illustrator I would be very grateful as it is the programme I use most.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Easy depends on what you're trying to do. Without seeing the what you're trying to vectorize, I am unable to give advise on what to do.

Answer (score 1):

There's no quick and easy way to duplicate the logo perfectly. Illustrator has live trace features that attempt to vectorize raster images, but those are more useful for photos. If you try to live trace a logo it will look noticeably different.

The best way to do this is to paste the image into Illustrator and recreate it in vector on another layer. Depending on the logo, you'll need to be able to use the pen tool, the various shapes, and the pathfinder window.

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful answer! I've realized that there isn't a specific quick and easy way, but I was more thinking that there might be ways that are better than others.